# Kill Java Thread In Linux

Tags: java, linux, java-threads, kill-process

In Linux Server, I have One Java Application...
Sometimes Its Thread Gone Stuck..
How Can I Find Them And Kill That Particular Thread of Java.
I want to kill that java thread who takes more then 5 minute of time 
Top -H result as image

[image]

Comment: Don't say type kill -9 <process id> I want to create shell script which will detect its own process id.

Comment: You should include the creation of a shell script as part of the question.

Comment: I had it already here and removed it because I though: It doesn't realy help you - but FWIW: the pid of a shell script is usually $$. ps and jps list processes and yes you can filter (grep) for specific name and time - also a starttime and kill it. But is that what you realy want? BTW processes that are blocked by resource can't be killed.

Comment: Try `kill -9 $(ps -eo comm,pid,etimes | awk '/^processname/ {if ($3 > 300) { print $2}}')`. Don't know if you can find the `processname` for your application. Here 300 is running time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't only kill a thread of a process, if you use the command "kill -9 threadNo", you will kill the process.

Answer (score -2):

Find java process using below

`$ ps -fea | grep -i java`

Here is the sample output
user  2895  8191  0 09:28 pts/1    00:00:00 grep -i java
user  `4610`  4607  1 Aug29 ?        01:40:00 /home/user/Software/java-7-sun/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms40m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar /home/user/Software/springsource/sts-3.3.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar

and then kill the process

`$ kill -9 4610`

As you want to automate this via Shell, to get pid, further search in the text with your specific java app (probably search location of app)

`ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep`

Extract PID portion using SED

Comment: OP says *I want to kill that java thread who takes more then 5 minute of time*